# Urldecode in batch file

Tags: url, batch-file, urldecode

How can I 'urldecode' the following string in a batch file? I need to change the following

```
http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.example.com&#x2f;some-page&#x2f;some&#x2f;link.html
```

to this

```
http://www.example.com/some-page/some/link.html
```

It can be done in Javascript with decodeURIComponent() but I've no idea how to do it in a batch file just within MSDOS etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be achieved in pure Batch...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "input=http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.example.com&#x2f;some-page&#x2f;some&#x2f;link.html"

rem Define the equivalences
for %%a in ("#x3a=:" "#x2f=/") do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in (%%a) do set "replace[%%b]=%%c"
)

echo Input = "%input%"
set "input=%input:&=\%"
set "output="
for %%a in (%input%) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%b in ("%%a")  do (
      if "%%c" neq "" (
         set "output=!output!%%b!replace[%%c]!"
      ) else (
         set "term=%%a"
         if "!term:~0,1!" equ "\" (
            set "output=!output!!replace[%%b]!"
         ) else (
            set "output=!output!%%b"
         )
      )
   )
)
echo Output = "%output%"
```

Comment: What... How did... Mmmfh!  There's no calculation of anything here, no conversion of hex to dec to charcode, just a lot of code to perform a direct conversion from `&#x3a;` to `:` and `&#x2f;` to `/`.  You could've just done `set "input=%input:&#x3a;=:%"` and `set "input=%input:&#x2f;=/%"` and called it a day, you know.  :)  Challenge: Scrape `&#xNN;` and convert NN to the ASCII character it represents.

Answer (score 4):

> It can be done in Javascript with decodeURIComponent() but I've no idea how to do it in a batch file just within MSDOS etc.

Not with `decodeURIComponent()`, no.  Be that as it may, the solution still lies with invoking JavaScript.  You can call on the IE7 JavaScript engine via JScript.  [See this page](https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/5199433) for more examples of batch + JScript hybrid scripts.

There are no built-in JavaScript functions to convert HTML entities (the `&#xFF;` characters) back to plain text, but it's not too difficult to roll your own.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal

set "url=http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.example.com&#x2f;some-page&#x2f;some&#x2f;link.html"

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%url%"

goto :EOF

@end
// JScript portion

function decodeEntities(what) {
    return what.replace(/&#x([0-9a-f]{2});/ig, function(m, $1) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt($1, 16));
    });
}

WSH.Echo(decodeEntities(WSH.Arguments(0)));
```

---

Just as an academic exercise, here's a pure batch method of converting HTML character entities to ASCII.  It's slightly slower than the JScript hybrid, and it'll probably mistreat strings containing exclamation marks.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "url=http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.example.com&#x2f;some-page&#x2f;some&#x2f;link.html"

set "url=%url:&#x=;0x%"

:begin
for %%I in (%url%) do (
    set "chunk=%%~I"
    if "!chunk:~0,2!"=="0x" if "!chunk:~4,1!"=="" (
            for /f "delims=" %%x in (
                'forfiles /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%%~I"'
            ) do set "url=!url:;%%I;=%%~x!"
            goto begin
        )
    )
)

echo !url!
```

Comment: I replaced the `http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab` string in the following W3Schools site with the string I want to decode. It decoded it successfully so I thought it was a Javascript method. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_decodeuricomponent

Comment: @user2146441 `decodeURI` and similar decode percent codes -- `http%3A%2F%2F` and similar.  Maybe either your browser or the w3schools backend translated the entities for you.  *shrug*  If I run your string through `decodeURI` in JScript, it ends exactly as it started.  There are no percent codes to decode.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @if (@x)==(@y) @end /***** jscript comment ******
     @echo off
    set "url=http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.example.com&#x2f;some-page&#x2f;some&#x2f;link.html"
     cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%url%" 
     exit /b 0

 @if (@x)==(@y) @end ******  end comment *********/

 var args=WScript.Arguments;
 //WScript.Echo(args.Item(0));
 WScript.Echo(decodeURIComponent(args.Item(0)));
```

though this definitely is not uri encoded url...