# PHP proc_open() escape multiline argument

Tags: php, powershell, batch-file, cmd, newline

I'm tring to pass a string to a batch file from php using `proc_open()` on Windows. It works fine unless the string I'm passing is multiline, because it breaks the command with the line break. I tried various escaping methods, but none of them seems to work:

cmd style - prints the escape symbol and breaks line:

```
proc_open('script.bat -m "this is ^\n multiline"', $desc, $pipes)
```

another try - prints the whole string:

```
proc_open('script.bat -m "this is ^\\n multiline"', $desc, $pipes)
```

powershell style - prints the whole string:

```
proc_open('script.bat -m "this is `n multiline"', $desc, $pipes)
```

No matter what I tried,  it either breaks the string anyway,  or prints it as is, with no line break.

What am I missing or doing wrong? How to get multiline arguments to work via `proc_open()`?

Comment: Looks like you are missing an apostrophe - ' after the " before the ,  so for example the first one should be:  proc_open('script.bat -m "this is ^\n multiline"', $desc, $pipes);  you are opening an apostrophe  ' string in all of your tries but not closing it....

Comment: @Shlomtzion I'm sorry, my mistake when trying to reproduce the problem. I edited the question. However it doesn't relate to the point of the question, as I have it fine in my actual script.

Comment: In the powershell example you are not missing the ' - apostrophe ... that is probably why it works there....

Comment: @Shlomtzion I have the closing apostrophe in my actual script. This was just my mistake while writing an example for sake of this question.

Comment: hmm, it sounds like something that urlencode will solve, there is a way to urldecode string within a batch file...I am really spitting balls here :) I have no idea if it will work. but if you want to try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221685/urldecode-in-batch-file

Comment: As of PHP 7.4, the first parameter to [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) can be an array of command parameters, and PHP will handle the escaping for you. I can guarantee it will solve your problem, but I’d try that.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get it escaped properly, it's nearly impossible, that your batch file is able to fetch a multi line argument.

You should test the batch script on it's own directly from `cmd.exe`, before trying to fix the escaping in php

```
c:\> script.bat This_is_^
More? 
More? multiline
```

A simple `echo %*` or `set "arg=%~1"` is not able to handle multi line arguments, but some hacks like:
[How to receive even the strangest command line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55689910/463115)
[Im passing a multi line text as argument which will ... has only 1 line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42843711/463115)